# Create columns based on unique values

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create columns in a SELECT query based on unique values from another column?

For instance I have two tables item and characteristic, an item can have multiple characteristics.

item:

```
item_id | price
i1        0.13
i2        0.40
i3        0.24
...
```

characteristic:

```
char_id | item_id | char_value
c001      i1        2
c498      i1        6
c001      i2        4
c265      i2        1
c378      i3        9
...       ...       ...
```

What I want the output for the SQL query to be is

```
item_id | price | c001 | c265 | c378 | c498
i1        0.13    2      null   null   6
i2        0.40    4      1      null   null
i3        0.24    null   null   9      null
...
```

Keep in mind there can be a lot of different char_ids so manually defining the columns to be `c001`, `c265`, `c378` and `c498` is not an option. Manually defining each column would require me to write hundreds of lines of SQL query.

Is there a way to create an SQL query that can do this?